# Bootstrap notification - Rapidly calling method causes notifications to freeze on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML button that calls a function to make a bootstrap notification appear on the screen. There is also a built-in jQuery method to make the notifications fade after 1 second.

The method works fine, but if I call the method(i.e click the button) in rapid succession, the notifications seem to "freeze" on the page and the page must be refreshed to remove the frozen notifications.

I have tried tinkering with various jQuery event handlers that will allow all of the visible notifications to eventually fade after a certain period of time. Nothing I have tried so far has worked the way I need it to.

Here is the JS method that is tied to the button click, makes the notification appear, and makes it fadeOut.

```
function showDiv() {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<div id="newAlert" class="alert alert- 
    info">Hello</div>'
    document.body.appendChild(div);
   $("#newAlert").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
   $("#newAlert").remove();
});
}
```

I want to set this up so that no matter how many times I fire that method, each notification that appears will fade after 1 second. Any recommendations on how I can go about fixing this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: How "rapidly" are we talking? What you are trying to do may not be possible. Your notifications  may be freezing due to your client not being able to keep up with the code execution.

Comment: I may be wrong but I'm guessing it's because you use `#newAlert` as an ID, and there may be more than one div with that ID. If that is the case maybe you can set the ID as math.random() so that it will be unique every time you call the method.

Comment: @IskandarRezaRazali This is a good point, but I feel like using a class for this would be better supported, especially if there is some event you can use to check if the class you are using was added to the dom, and if it was, use `$(this)` to fade it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the id is the same with all of them. This is a terrible idea but should work.

```
function showDiv() {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    let id = new Date().getTime();
    div.innerHTML = `<div id="${id}" class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>`
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    setTimeout(() => {
        $("#"+id).fadeOut("slow", function() {
          $("#"+id).remove();
        });
    }, 1000)

}
```

Comment: `<div id="${id}" ` does this actually work? I thought we have to do it like this:  `'<div id="' + id +'" `

Comment: Notice the ``, js supports template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Comment: Note that this leaves *garbage* of empty `div`s

Comment: @AlexKudryashev `This is a terrible idea`

Comment: @infamoustrey `id` is redundant here. `let div...` already refers to the `div` and there is no need to locate it with `$("#"+id)`. External `div` was not removed in the answer.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev `This is a terrible idea`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in `id` at all. Object reference already exist. Also jQuery allows to do everything in a single statement. Something like this.

```js
function showDiv() {
  $("<div/>")
    .html('<div class="alert alert-info">Hello</div>')
    .appendTo('#notif')//or body
    .delay(1000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).remove();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="showDiv()">show</button>
<div id="notif"></div>
```

Comment: Great answer, but I need the div to appear only when the button is clicked, it can't exist on the page beforehand. Appreciate the answer though!

Comment: This is exactly what you ask for. The `div` appears only when you click the button. Even more, it disappears and doesn't leave garbage (empty `div`).